# Implement event handlers for QWidget and derived classes and avoid code duplication

Tags: python, qt, events, pyside, qwidget

I made a clickable `QWidget` by inheriting from it as follows in Python (using a Python-Qt binding):

```
class ClickableWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtGui.QMouseEvent)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit(event)
```

Of course more events and more signals could be implemented.

I want to add the same functionality to `QLabel`, `QToolBar`, .. This could of course be done easily the same way resulting in a lot of code duplication.

Is there a better alternative in the sense that there is minimal code duplication and the code is efficient and easy maintainable? What would be the most Qt-like/Pythonic way?

One alternative might be to install an event filter on the Qt-application(?) to filter for all events going to any of the desired widgets but this might get complex by itself having to differentiate between the target objects..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function to define the subclasses

```
def createClickableSubclass(parent):
    class ClickableSubclass(parent):
        clicked_ = QtCore.Signal(QtGui.QMouseEvent)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(ClickableSubclass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            self.clicked_.emit(event)

    return ClickableSubclass


MyLabel = createClickableSubclass(QtGui.QLabel)
MyToolBar = createClickableSubclass(QtGui.QToolBar)
```

---

**Edit:** with reference to your comment, you would use the subclasses like this:

```
aLabel = MyLabel('Label text')
aLabel.setStyleSheet('color: yellow')
```

Comment: My Python knowledge is definitely not comprehensive. You can define classes inside a function? What will be the type name of the created class? How would you for example specify it in a stylesheet?

Comment: Yes you can, functions too (this is how decorators work). The name of the class is whatever you choose to assign it to, in the case of my example this is `MyLabel` and `MyToolBar`. These are not instances of the class but a handle to the definition of the class itself.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be declined by someone who knows better. So maybe you could fix the super(parent, ..)  which gives an error (or state it's Python 2.X) and also please add (if you want) a class selector in the stylesheet ".MyLabel{color:yellow}" to show again the class name is MyLabel.

Comment: Thanks, that one slipped by me. I've made the edit now.